# Output bash script into file (without >> )

Tags: bash

Perhaps this is very simple thing, but yet I dont know it.
I have a job specified in cron, which calls a script once in a while.

something like that: `1 1 * * * bash script.sh`

Now, when script launched it reads configuration and realises that all output needs to be appended to log file.

The simple solution would be to update cron task like `1 1 * * * bash script.sh >> log`
But let assume that name and location of the file is not known at this stage.

So I came up with the solution which works, but I dont like it a lot.
Code at the top of the script:

source config.sh

```
N=$#
LAST_ARG=${!N}
if [ "$LAST_ARG" != "log" ]
then
  bash \`basename $0\` \`echo $@ log\` >>  "$LogFile"
  exit
fi
```

I recursively launching the same script, with additional argument, and direction to log file. Then Parent instance just getting closed.

Sure there has to be a better way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: It looks as though that script would still need to be initially called with a log file as the last argument. How would you call that from cron?

Comment: Not sure if it fits the bill, but maybe you could use an environment variable? `1 1 * * * bash script.sh >> $LOG_FILE` The main question is why is the location of the log file unknown? Perhaps you're doing something too clever ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
exec 1>/the/file/name.log
```

This will redirect stdout to /the/file/name.log

Comment: Well, you probably want `>>` not `>` but the idea's the same.