# how to log all the command output to one single file in bash scripting

Tags: bash

In gnu/Linux i want to log all the command output to one particular file.
Say in terminal,i am typing

`echo "Hi this is a dude"`

It should print in the file name specified earlier without using the redirection in every command.

Comment: Check out this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171350/output-bash-script-into-file-without?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commands launched from the shell inherit the file descriptor to use for standard output from the shell. In your typical interactive shell, standard output is the terminal. You can change that by using the `exec` command:

```
exec > output.txt
```

Following that command, the shell itself will write its standard output to a file called output.txt, and any command it spawns will do likewise, unless otherwise redirected. You can always "restore" output to the terminal using

```
exec > /dev/tty
```

Note that your shell prompt and text you type at the prompt continue to be displayed on the screen (since the shell writes both of those to standard error, not standard output).

Comment: Cool. An improvement: `exec > >(tee -a output.txt)` lets the output go to the file and the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ script x1
Script started, file is x1
$ echo "Hi this is a dude"
Hi this is a dude
$ echo "done"
done
$ exit
exit
Script done, file is x1
```

Then, the contents of file x1 are:

```
Script started on Thu Jun 13 14:51:29 2013
$ echo "Hi this is a dude"
Hi this is a dude
$ echo "done"
done
$ exit
exit

Script done on Thu Jun 13 14:51:52 2013
```

You can easily edit out your own commands and start/end lines using basic shell scripting (`grep -v`, especially if your Unix prompt has a distinctive substring pattern)

Answer (score 1):

Output redirection can be achieved in bash with `>`: [See this link for more info on bash redirection.](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

You can run any program with ported output and all its output will go to a file, for example:

```
$ ls > out
$ cat out
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
eclipse
Firefox_wallpaper.png
...
```

So, if you want to open a new shell session with ported output, just do so!:

```
$ bash > outfile
```

will start a new bash session porting all of stdout to that file.

```
$ bash &> outfile
```

will port all of stdout AND stderr to that file (meaning you will no longer see prompts show up in your terminal)

For example:

```
$ bash > outfile
$ echo "hello"
$ echo "this is an outfile"
$ cd asdsd
bash: cd: asdsd: No such file or directory
$ exit
exit
$ cat outfile
hello
this is an outfile
$

$ bash &> outfile
echo "hi"
echo "this saves everythingggg"
cd asdfasdfasdf
exit
$ cat outfile
hi
this saves everythingggg
bash: line 3: cd: asdfasdfasdf: No such file or directory
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{ command1 ; command2 ; command3 ; } > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output and have it written to a file (say for later analysis) then you can use the `tee` command.

```
$ echo "hi this is a dude" | tee hello
hi this is a dude
$ ls
hello
$ cat hello
hi this is a dude
```

tee is a useful command because it allows you to store everything that goes into it as well as displaying it on the screen. Particularly useful for logging the output of scripts.